# Error sending transaction to smart contract

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript

I have problem with this, I'm doing a tutorial about how to interact with blockchain through web3, I get some response from blockchain, but the problem is when I try to send transaction or try to interact with smart contract. When I clicked on the send button I have an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: myContract is not defined, how ever, before this the code is working well, the data is showed and everything looks fine, but when I clicked the error and the function doesn't work.

I'm working on localhost, remix and metamask. Not ganache/rpc/geth deployed. Just want to connect to blockchain from a HTML file.

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Testing web3 connection</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

<script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="abi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Web 3 test</h1>
        Welcome to our token creator site 
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        Your address is:<strong><div id="mywallet"></div></strong>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        Contract Owner: <br><strong><div id="owner"></div></strong>  
        <p></p>
        Total Supply: <br><strong><div id="total"></div></strong>  
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" id="amount">
        <p></p>
        <button id="sending">Send</button>
    <strong><div id="txStatus"></div></strong> 

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
        if (window.ethereum) {
                window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
                try {
                    await ethereum.enable();
                    if (web3) {

                    switch (web3.version.network) {
                        case '1':
                            console.log('This is mainnet');
                            break;
                        case '2':
                            console.log('This is the deprecated Morden test network.');
                            break;
                        case '3':
                            console.log('This is the ropsten test network.');
                            break;
                        case '4':
                            console.log('This is the Rinkeby test network.');
                            break;
                        case '42':
                            console.log('This is the Kovan test network.');
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log('This is an unknown network.');
                    }


                    var desiredNetwork = 4;
                    if (web3.version.network != desiredNetwork){ 
                       // alert('Please switch to main network.');
                    }  

                    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accounts){
                    if (err != null) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else if (accounts.length === 0){ 
                        console.log('MetaMask is locked');
                        alert('Please connect to MetaMask');
                    } else {
                        console.log('MetaMask is unlocked')
                    }
                    }); 
                    //This data is showed in the test file on localhost, so I got response from blockchain    
                    account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

                    $('#mywallet').html(account); 

                    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myABI, '0xf65eFbCA9C36299AD50CF177bdE261973661174D');
                    var owner = await myContract.methods.owner().call();
                    $('#owner').html(owner); 
      //End data response                                   
                    }      

                } catch (error) {

                }
            }

            // Legacy dapp browsers...
            else if (window.web3) {
                window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

            }
            // Non-dapp browsers...
            else {
                console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask or Trust Wallet!');
            }
   });


                     $("#sending").click(function() {
                        //when I clicked here an error appears => Uncaught ReferenceError: myContract is not defined
                        var id = $('#name').val();
                        var amount = $('#amount').val();
                        myContract.methods.addName(id , amount, account).send();
                     }); 

</script>
```

I have been testing for a week, and I can't see my error.

Comment: Variable `myContract` is local where you declare it, so it is obviously not recognazied outside of that scope. This is a purely Javascript question, and it has nothing to do with Ethereum, so I have voted to close it.

Comment: I declared the variables and test several situations, but is not working. Any working example I can use to interact with smart contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this via web3 + java:

```
    //Check if the object is definied
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    }

    //Init my constant
    const contractAddress = 'MY CONTRACT ADDRESS HERE';
    // I created my contract instance
    const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(myABI, 'MY CONTRACT ADDRESS');

    //As I'm working with promises, I need an async function
    //to get the blockchain data and to interact with blockchain

    async function getDetais() {
        //maybe there is a better option that getaccount, this works for me
        const account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        $('#mywallet').html(account);

        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(account[0]);
        const balanceinETH = balance/1000000000000000000;
        $('#mybalance').html(balanceinETH +' ETH'); 

        const ContractOwner = await myContract.methods.owner().call();
        $('#owner').html(ContractOwner); 

        const BaseURL =  await myContract.methods.url().call();
        $('#BaseURL').html(BaseURL);

        const totalSupply =  await myContract.methods.totalSupply().call();
        $('#total').html(totalSupply);

        $("#sending").click(function() {
         //I need to set up the value of gas inside the send function. See 
         //web3 documentation to know more about it   
         myContract.methods.createToken($("#name").val(), $("#fdate").val()).send({from: account[0], to: contractAddress, gas: 2100000});
    });

    }
    //I call my function
    getDetais();
```

with this code you can interact with blockchain smart contract very easy.

Answer (score 0):

you have to shift the sending function to the main file which contains the myContract instance(where you deployed/assigned your contract which includes your abis).You can do that by assigning id to tags on frontend .You better try REACTJS ,it will be useful.

Comment: I'm really noob in react, trying html to use it with PHP and mysql

Comment: are u specified ur contract address and abis to mycontract variable?